# Can parted show used and available sizes as gparted?

Tags: gparted, parted

gparted is said to be the GUI frontend of parted.

Why can't parted   show used and available sizes for each partition, as gparted does?

If parted can, how can I make it show that information?

If not, how does gparted make it?

```
$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for t: 
Model: ATA ST1000LM014-1EJ1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      116GB   716GB   600GB   ext4
 3      716GB   1000GB  284GB   ext4
```

[image]

Comment: Because it doesn't have this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line, the used and unused space on each filesystem can be listed using the command `df`, assuming that the filesystems are mounted.

If you wanted to be pedantic, you could say more accurately that "`gparted` is a graphical frontend for `parted` and any combination of `btrfs-progs`/`btrfs-tools`, `e2fsprogs`, `f2fs-tools`, `dosfstools`/`mtools`, `hfsutils`, `hfsprogs` , `jfsutils`, `util-linux`, `lvm2`, `nilfs-utils`, `ntfs-3g`/`ntfsprogs`, `reiser4progs`, `reiserfsprogs`/`reiserfs-utils`, `xfsprogs` and/or `xfsdump`"... but I think that would be too cumbersome for general use. I believe that the tools and/or libraries in those packages could include the functionality to find out the used/unused capacity on each supported filesystem, if that functionality isn't integrated into the main `gparted` binary.

So, yes, `gparted` is a frontend for `parted`... but not **just** a simple frontend: since the GUI allows for more easier presentation of complex concepts, it uses that capability to provide more advanced functionality. In doing so, it acts as a frontend for way more tools than just `parted` alone.

Comment: Thanks. It is not I want to be pedantic. When A is said to be GUI frontend of B, it usually implies B has more feature than A, or is more powerful, So I think it is best to use the CLI program than the GUI one.